# send data from php server to vb.net client

Tags: php, vb.net, websocket, request, push

I want to send data from online PHP website to a client program (vb.net, but can be another language) without request. I mean that I have a website where customers make something and receive these data on a desktop.

> ```
>                     (no request)
> ```
>
> PHP script from website -------------------------> vb.net on a desktop

Which is the best way for you? Can I use websockets or there are better and simple way to do this? Or I reads data from vb.net timing the task?

ty

Comment: Check out [CURL](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Can cURL send a file from the website to a client PC without a web server?

Answer (score 0):

let me explain #one thing to you :
if you want to send data to any PC or Any Client You Need to connect to it using IP on some port wich mean Client Device must be Forwarding the port you trying to access from and that may be difficult for some users , so i suggest that you use PHP Function called "Fopen()"
use it to save data to some file in your website and make it readable like a text file and here Example :

```
<?
$inputString = "Data you want to send to Desktop";
$fp = fopen( "yourfile.txt" , "w" );
fwrite($fp, $inputString);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

and then just read the file from Desktop Client By visting the URL of the file :

http://www.yoursite.com/path/yourfile.txt

and the data will be there so after you get that data just Do What Ever You want with it.

Comment: ty, that's can be a way, the only my dubt is that I needs to check periodically if the file exist or if it contain new data. I hoped there was something more real time and automaticaly...